# List items displaying over menu on website

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't figure out why the list items on [my website](https://papojari.codeberg.page/) are displaying on top of my logo and the menu. Have a look yourself on the website or this image: [a screenshot of the https://papojari.codeberg.page/art/ website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/civ4o.png) Some time ago I had the same issue with headings. The headings were in the `post-title` class because of a template I use. When I removed that class, the problem was gone. My list items don't have a class like that though and I can't find any references to that class and what it does. You can obviously have a look at the CSS on [the website](https://papojari.codeberg.page/) but additionally the source code is also here: https://codeberg.org/papojari/pages.

Please tell me how to stop the list items from displaying on top of my logo and the menu.

Comment: Give your CSS those lines of code and it will work: `header { z-index: 999;
position: relative; }` We just tell it to be above the rest of the page.

Comment: "*You can obviously have a look at the CSS on the website but additionally the source code is also [over there]...*" - no; questions here on Stack Overflow are required to put the relevant "*[mcve]*" code *in* the question. Please don't expect us to follow you around the internet in order to help you. Also, take a read of the "*[ask]*" guidance to see what we expect of questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@papojari, I have checked your site and I think that it's the problem of the z-index between and header and main section.

Here is the adding style for fixing it.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Use this code to fix directly

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

### Reason

You need `z-index` to control the vertical stacking order of elements. And `z-index` only affects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

Take a look of this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: There is no element on the site that has the `header` class.

Comment: @Laisender oh, you're right.

Comment: A class would have the `.` prefix. So it applies to header **elements** which there are some of one the site.